# Meteor js Windows install error "Failed to contact install server"

Tags: javascript, meteor, javascript-framework

I have tried running the install with "Run as Admin" feature on windows too, but the same issue persists.
I see this question has been posted before but still no resolution given.
Basically the following error message comes in the middle of the install and the install stops. Please help.

Error message:
"Failed to contact install server. Please try again later."

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Node js already installed before installing meteorjs other wise it crashes on Windows sometimes hope it helped.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 1):

Install meteor with this installer: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows

If you are behind a proxy set these parameters HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY: [Using Meteor behind a proxy](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy)

Update your meteor installation: meteor update

The meteor will be updated to the last version.

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows/2e876f1bb8ffe83e38e82b92bca130bff7509d89

Answer (score 0):

install from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows (the >60MB file) and set the user.meteor folder in your path
the problem with windows installation is too long pathnames (>256) so better try a linux VM