# Meteor installation/updation problems on Windows 7

Tags: meteor

I'm tried to install Meteor on Windows 7:

I downloaded the installer from the [official download link](https://www.meteor.com/install). Upon trying to install it, I get the error `Failed to contact install server`.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013958/3507137) over here I successfully managed to install an older version of Meteor: but now neither `meteor update` nor any other command works. The response I get is:

> This project uses Meteor 1.2.1, which isn't available on Windows. To work with this app on all supported platforms, use meteor update --release METEOR@1.2.1 to pin this app to the newest Windows-compatible release.

The suggested command generates the same response. Any workarounds?